# Complex for loop with an empty body

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, initialization

I have taken a JavaScript function that shuffles array elements with the help of a `for` loop that accepts arguments but doesn't have a body (empty body).

After the `for` loop evaluates the array elements are shuffled. This is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Gurbanov/pen/bEXxxy).

Here is the function's code:

```
function shuffle( array ) { // Shuffle an array
    // 
    // +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com)


    for(var j, x, i = array.length;
            i; 
            j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
            x = array[--i], array[i] = array[j], array[j] = x){     

    }
    return array; 
}
console.log(shuffle(['Kevin', 'van', 'Zonneveld']));
```

If the loop doesn't have a body, can I initialize all the elements outside of the `for` loop? Like below:

```
var j, x, i = array.length; 
var j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = array[--i], array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = x;
```

Comment: The loop doesn't have any statements in its body, but it *does* still need to be a loop because it does still run for a number of iterations. Put some console.log() statements inside the loop to log all the variables and you'll see what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may initialize your variables before the `for` loop, but not in the way you specified.
The [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) of a `for` loop is:

```
for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])
   statement // for you this is empty - no statement
```

The initialization step as you can see is the first one, before the first semicolon (`;`). So a correct initialization would be:

```
var j, x, i = array.length;
```

But not:

```
var j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = array[--i], array[i] = array[j];
array[j] = x;
```

As these are the condition and final expression steps. Note that your loop will end when the condition `!i` is met.
There is no reason to perform this tough. And if you do, make sure you only omit the initialization part of the `for` loop and not any of the others.

An easier way to view this loop is:

```
for (
     // initialisation: declare three variables
     var j, x, i = array.length;
     // The loop check: when it gets to `!i`, it will exit the loop
     i;
     // the increment clause, made of several "sub-statements"
     j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
     x = array[--i],
     array[i] = array[j],
     array[j] = x
)
    { } // The body of the loop is an empty statement
```

For the sake of completeness, you may also find it more understandable to view an equivalent `while` loop to this `for` loop (notice how the initialization is before the loop here):

```
var j, x, i = array.length;
while (i) {
     j = parseInt(Math.random() * i);
     x = array[--i];
     array[i] = array[j];
     array[j] = x;
}
```

Comment: why here is used for loop? loop is intended for to implement code from one till another point. here for loop is implemented one time in each function call

Comment: No, it is run multiple times depending on the condition and final expression. You can try to run it and see for yourself... it will run until the `condition` part is not met.

Comment: I did console.log and i saw three times it loops and in every loop i is decremented. if nowhere we declared that condition let i decrement, why i is decremented, second is we take one of three result why needed loop? simply math.random does it? isn't it?

Comment: You can see that `i` is decremented inside the command `x = array[--i];` . The `--i` decrements `i` (even if it is not in a stand-alone statement). And we don't just "take one of three results".. The loop runs for however many times that it needs to (it can run more or less times, you can check this with different arrays)

Comment: Does i depends on array[--i]? if i dont increment i or decrement i and if i decremented inside array index does it affects i?

Comment: If it didn't have the `array[--i]` then the loop will never end. You can certainly decrement it not in the array index. There is no problem in writing: `--i` and then `array[i]`. That will be equivalent